# Crystal report talking long time to load

Tags: sql, vba, crystal-reports

i am using SQL 2005, and CR 8.5, some of my report that is taking about 10 minutes to load when opened through the application, anybody know what is the problem and solution to solve ?

Comment: How long does the report take when run in the Report Designer? How long does the query take when run through a SQL client?

Comment: I'm curious if you added the `vba` tag for a reason?

Comment: Mark's question is an excellent one. It would let us know if your query is very slow, or if it's just Crystal doing it. Personally, I'd also be upgrading off of technology made over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

From the Crystal Reports designer, goto the `Report` menu and select `Performance Information` this should give you some more information about what is taking so long.

I've not used CR 8.5 (the oldest version i've used is CR XI). But hopefully the feature has been around for some time.

Answer (score 0):

It might because you've not limited the data using an index field, if possible it's always quicker to include a filter on an indexed field, even if it's not exact it can reduce the number of items being checked drastically.